# Replacing correlated sub-query with JOIN(s) only?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, subquery, correlated-subquery

This question is somewhat a follow up to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966797/is-it-a-slow-query-can-it-be-improved). It's also based on [SQLZOO's "SELECT within SELECT tutorial"](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial). This time it's about *Task# 8*.

First, an acceptable solution:

```
SELECT w1.name, w1.continent FROM world w1
WHERE w1.population > ALL(
SELECT w2.population*3 FROM world w2
WHERE w2.continent=w1.continent and w2.name<>w1.name)
```

This time a correlated query is deeply ingrained in the logic.

Can this query still be **reasonably** rewritten with JOIN(s) only?  Should it be?

Answer (score 2):

So the task 8 says: Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

I find it a bit a unclear. Which are the neighbors? Is this all the countries on the continent? If yes then the next question is if we compare against the smallest neighbor or the largest neighbor. Let's say it is the largest neighbor. Then the query would be something like this

```
select name, continent
  from world w1
 where w1.population > (select max(3*w2.population) 
                          from world w2
                         where w2.continent =  w1.continent
                           and w2.name      <> w1.name)
```

Otherwise if it would be 3 times of all neighbors together it would be this

```
select name, continent
  from world w1
 where w1.population > (select 3*sum(w2.population) 
                          from world w2
                         where w2.continent =  w1.continent
                           and w2.name      <> w1.name)
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: Oracle SQL manual (E26088-01) says about ALL function:

> Compares a value to every value in a list or returned by a query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE salary >=
ALL ( 1400, 3000)
ORDER BY employee_id;
```

With aggregation first and then comparing we reduce it to one comparison. The result in the given example table is the same. But the query against ALL countries could actually give a different result. So after all I must say your query is better. If you have in a continent a country with population of 1 mio, 3.5 mio, and 11 mio then actually the 2nd country is 3 times the first and the 3rd country is 3 times the 2nd. My query would only compare the 2nd country to the 3rd but your query compares also the first to the second.

Comment: This is the 1st case: countries that at least 3 times more populous than all other **individual** countries on the same continent.

Do you believe that your query any better (i.e. more efficient) than mine?

Comment: Minimally more efficient probably. I will edit the post to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular query, you need the largest and second largest values on each continent.  I would approach this with window functions:

```
select w.continent,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then w.name end) as name
from (select w.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by continent order by population desc) as seqnum
      from world w
     ) w
where seqnum in (1, 2)
group by continent
having max(case when seqnum = 1 then population end) > 3*max(case when seqnum = 2 then population end)
```

Ok, I admit that this is probably a bit advanced, given the source of the question.

So, here is a way you can do it using joins, instead of correlated subqueries:

I think the following does your logic:

```
select w.name, w.continent
from world w join
     (SELECT w.continent, maxpopulation,
             max(case when population <> maxpopulation then population end) as secondmax
      FROM world w join
           (select continent, max(population) as maxpopulation
            from world
            group by continent
           ) c
           on w.continent = c.continent
      group by w.continent, maxpopulation
     ) wc
     on w.continent = wc.continent and w.population = maxpopulation
where population >= 3*secondmax
```

So the answer is "yes, you can do this without correlated subqueries."  In most common cases, you can rewrite correlated subqueries using joins and group bys.

Comment: As a note . . . I've totally rewritten the answer since this comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very interesting.
Your 1st query is working as intended. Oracle, however, complains about the 2nd one. I wasn't able to find a fix.
When you have a moment could you possibly revisit it?